# Update multi fields in multi shape files with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have 3 shapefiles belongs to one state "District", "Mandal", "Village".

These three shapefiles have the same fields like DName, MName, VName.

I want to update all field in all shapefiles at a the same time with ArcPy update cursor.

I am new for ArcPy i tried but getting for single shapefile.

Answer (score 2):

You'll just need a `for` loop to iterate through multiple items (in this case, strings of the paths to your shapefiles) if you wish to perform the same procedure on multiple items.

A basic template:

```
import arcpy

#Paths to shapefiles
distFc = r"C:\test\example\district.shp"
mandalFc = r"C:\test\example\mandal.shp"
villageFc = r"C:\test\example\village.shp"

#Create list of shapefiles
shapefiles = [distFc, mandalFc, villageFc]

#iterate through each shapefile with a for loop
for shp in shapefiles:
    #Create update cursor
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (shp, ["DName", "MName", "VName"]) as cursor:
        #iterate cursor
        for dName, mName, vName in cursor:
            # code goes here
```